# Combining Riverpod Providers Bidirectionally

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

How can we access a method from the **being wrapped** riverpod provider?

*ContentProvider* can access user value from *UserProvider* by using "watch". There is no problem for this direction. On the other hand, *UserProvider* also needs access to the methods of *ContentProvider*. So bidirectional communication is required.

For this case, I need to call *deleteContents* method from UserProvider.

I don't prefer to merge them to keep logic safe.

```
class ContentProviderNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  final User? currentUser;
  ContentProviderNotifier({required this.currentUser});
  
  addContent(Content content) {    
    content.user = currentUser?.name;
    ...
  }

  deleteContents() {
    ...
  }

}

final contentProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<ContentProviderNotifier>(
  (ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider).currentUser;
    return ContentProviderNotifier(currentUser: user);
  },
);
```

```
class UserProviderNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  UserProviderNotifier();
  User? currentUser;

  deleteUsers(){
     // here to call a method from contentProvider
     deleteContents();
  }

}

final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProviderNotifier>(
  (ref) {
    return UserProviderNotifier();
  },
);
```

If I try to feed UserProvider with ContentProvider like this

```
final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProviderNotifier>(
  (ref) {
    final content = ref.watch(contentProvider); // <----
    return UserProviderNotifier(content);
  },
);
```

But I know, It won't make sense.

*The type of 'userProvider' can't be inferred because it depends on itself through the cycle: contentProvider, userProvider.
Try adding an explicit type to one or more of the variables in the cycle in order to break the cycle.darttop_level_cycle*

Comment: "On the other hand, UserProvider also needs access to the methods of ContentProvider".  There's your problem.  Why should it?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz how could I trigger deleting contents after deleting users? I think they should be located in a different logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UserProviderNotifier so it takes ref as an input, like this:

```
class UserProviderNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  UserProviderNotifier(this.ref);

  final Ref ref;

  deleteUsers() {
    // here to call a method from contentProvider
    ref.watch(contentProvider.notifier).deleteContents();
  }

}

final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProviderNotifier>(
      (ref) {
    return UserProviderNotifier(ref);
  },
);
```

This [section of the Riverpod docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#obtaining-a-ref-from-a-provider) mentions this is a common use-case.